# Vertical align left, right columns to dynamic middle column of varying height using CSS only?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

In the jsfiddle example below, I'd like the left column (#left) and the right hand columns (#right) to vertically align to the middle of the middle column (#middle). The height of the middle column (#middle) can vary.

This is for **mobile devices**, hence the use of

```
text-overflow:ellipsis; 
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow:hidden;
```

This part seems to work as required on screen resize.

Can this be achieved using CSS only (no javascript)?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/TGsdg/4/

Comment: Here's a solution I was working on, using `display: table-cell` to vertically align the content: http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/4T8WU/1/ Unfortunately `overflow: hidden` doesn't seem to have an effect. Maybe the fiddle will give someone else an idea, though.

Comment: Got it to work, but only by using a fixed height. Is that unacceptable, though? http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/4T8WU/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to do this is to use display:table(-cell) with table-layout:fixed. This will only work, however, if your right & left colums can have a fixed width:

http://jsfiddle.net/TGsdg/7/